# Changing usercontrol background colour doesn't show on form

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm just porting a load of FoxPro code to VB.NET. I have a csslbuttonpanel user control with a background colour of skyblue. This control is dropped onto various winforms. If I change the colour in csslbuttonpanel to red the forms still show skyblue. 
Am I missing something?
Regards
Graham

```
  Public Class csslButtonPanel
     Inherits Panel
     Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
     InitializeComponent()
     BackColor = Color.Red
    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Where are you changing the color to red? In the designer or in the constructor of the csslButtonPanel?
And are you sure you're not setting the BackColor of the csslButtonPanel again in the .designer file of the form it's on, thus overwriting the color set in the constructor?

Comment: Thanks Stan, I was putting the code into the csslbuttonpanel.vb file. As Hans says I needed the attributes. This works fine although I don't like building these base panels, labels, textboxes etc in code. Surprised there isn't a visual way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened because you made a mistake in the first version of the UserControl.  You forgot to tell the designer what the default value is.  You can easily see this back in the Properties window.  Select one of the existing ones on the form and note how the BackColor property is displayed.  It is shown in **bold** type, indicating that its value is not the default.

And since it is wasn't the default, it recorded Color.SkyBlue in the form's InitializeComponent() method.  Changing the default in your UserControl now has no effect, it keeps using the value selected in the form's InitializeComponent() method.

What you *should* have done is tell the designer about the default with an attribute.  Like this:

```
<DefaultValue(GetType(Color), "255, 135, 206, 235")> _
Public Overrides Property BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return MyBase.BackColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        MyBase.BackColor = value
    End Set
End Property
```

The `<DefaultValue>` attribute informs the designer about the default, SkyBlue in this case.  Now the value doesn't get recorded in the form and changing your default in the user control can be effective.

Easy mistake, everybody makes it at least once.  The attribute format is pretty awkward for Color, that doesn't help.  Easy to fix however, simply copy/paste the snippet and change the string to "255, 255, 0, 0" to match Color.Red.  Rebuild. Go back to the form and right-click the BackColor property on the existing controls and select Reset.  They'll now turn Red.

Comment: Thanks for replying Hans. Where should this code go? User control csslButtonPanel or the form. Also does this go in the designer.vb code or just in the vb code.

Comment: In your UserControl, just the vb.code.  Nothing particularly wrong with UCs but you have the extra option to just inherit from a single control and completely alter the way it works.  UCs are good to contain multiple controls, don't use it if you only put a single control on it.

Comment: I've put the code in the designer.vb in the user control and that works perfectly. Thanks again, spent hours trying to track that one down!